# How to run two methods simultaneously

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Downoader down = new Downoader();
        Downoader down2 = new Downoader();
        down.downloadFromConstructedUrl("http:xxxxx", new File("./references/word.txt"), new File("./references/words.txt"));
        down2.downloadFromConstructedUrl("http:xxxx", new File("./references/word1.txt"), new File("./references/words1.txt"));
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Is it possible to run these two methods: `down.downloadFromConstructedUrl()` and `down2.downloadFromConstructedUrl()` simultaneously? If so, how?

Comment: Run these two methods in separate threads. You will find lot of examples on how to create and start thread.

Comment: Read the Java API doc for Thread: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: Welcome to the world of multithreading.

Answer (score 21):

You start two threads:

Try this:

```
// Create two threads:
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        new Downloader().downloadFromConstructedUrl("http:xxxxx",
                       new File("./references/word.txt"),
                       new File("./references/words.txt"));
    }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        new Downloader().downloadFromConstructedUrl("http:xxxxx",
                       new File("./references/word1.txt"),
                       new File("./references/words1.txt"));
    }
};

// Start the downloads.
thread1.start();
thread2.start();

// Wait for them both to finish
thread1.join();
thread2.join();

// Continue the execution...
```

(You may need to add a few try/catch blocks, but the above code should give you a good start.)

**Further reading:**

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using threads directly, you better use ExecutorService, and run all download tasks through this service. Something like:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Downloader down = new Downloader("http:xxxxx", new File("./references/word.txt"), new File("./references/words.txt"));
Downloader down2 = new Downloader("http:xxxx", new File("./references/word1.txt"), new File("./references/words1.txt"));

service.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(down, down2));
```

Your `Downloader` class must implement `Callable` interface.

Comment: How efficient is this? Is it more or less expensive than Threads?

Comment: It still uses Threads in the background, but it's easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), and run both methods on parallel using multithreading. You will have to override [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) and invoke [`Thread.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

Note that you will have to take care for synchronizing your methods.

Also note: You will get "real parallel run" only if your machine has 2+ cores, however, if it doesn't - the OS will simulate "parallel" run for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's what threads are for. A thread is a lightweight inner process used to run code in parallel to your "main thread".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

That would be what [concurrency and threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is for.

Answer (score 0):

You start two different threads, but they'll run truly parallel if you have at least a 2-core machine. Google Java multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. Multi-threaded or concurrent programming is a very wide and complicated topic, though.

Best get started here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/