# Java: Change a variable in method 1, use changed variable in method 2 using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

I have two methods: The first (MultiThreaded) waits for an input and depending on what you typed it prints 1, 2, 3, nothing or ends altogether. The second (Dumper) takes the current value of 1, 2 or 3 and prints it every 300ms (at least it should).
Both methods individually work fine (1 printing my desired value; 2 printing every 300ms), but I can't seem to get method 2 to take the value that method 1 just received, even though they are both running at the same time.

I searched for how to run both at the same time finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664036/how-to-run-two-methods-simultaneously), so I knew I had to use threads. Then how to use a variable from another method (or use one in both) finding  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289849/two-threads-using-a-same-variable) - however I guess the way I used volatile is not correct?

This is my code:

MultiThreaded.java

```
public class MultiThreaded extends Thread{
volatile int status ;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MultiThreaded().execute_input();
}

public MultiThreaded() {

}
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("BEGIN");
            while(true) new MultiThreaded().execute_input();
        }   

        public void execute_input() {
        int input;
        while (true) {
            try {
                input = System.in.read();
            } catch (Exception e) {input = 0;}
            switch(input) {
            case '1' :  
            case '2' :  
            case '3' :  
                status = input-'0';
                System.out.print(status);   
                break;
            case 'q':   //End
                return;
            default:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dumper.java

```
class Dumper extends Thread{
volatile int status;

      public static void main (String[] args) {
            new Dumper().run();
        }

      public void run() {
          while(true) printName();
          }

      private void printName() {
        System.out.print("[");
        System.out.print(status);
        System.out.println("]");
        try { Thread.sleep(300); }
        catch (Exception e) {}
      }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultiThreaded().start();
        new Dumper().start();
    }
}
```

I'm grateful for any advice as I am pretty lost at the moment. Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, As mention by @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Here you write two different method with different variable like `status`. it means variable status are not same. They shared nothing which you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any part of your code that ensures that both threads share the same `status`: just because they have the same name doesn't mean they're the same variable.

What you've done so far is say, in code, "both classes have their own variable status, and it *can* be modified out of thread", but now you still need to write the code that ensures that the manipulation actually happens. For instance, you can use a `setStatus(int s)` method on the Dumper that the MultiTreaded instance can call, or you can even directly manipulate the `dumper.status` variable.

Whatever you go with, at least one thread needs to know the other exists. For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Dumper device = new Dumper();
  MultiThreaded master = new MultiThreaded(device);
  master.start();
  device.start();
}
```

and in the MultiThreaded class,

```
Dumper device;

...

public MultiThreaded(Dumper device) {
  this.device = device;
}

public void execute_input() {
  ...
  device.status = status;
}
```