# Launch multiple main methods at the same time in JAVA without a bash script

Tags: java, bash, arguments, program-entry-point

I want to launch multiple main methods as clients for my program. and I should give each one separately its own arguments. Is there a way to do this without using a bash script ? And if not, is it a solution to actually develop another method and pass arguments as variables if possible ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a shell script?

Comment: By _variables_, do you mean environment variables ?

Comment: No, I mean variables inside the class.

Comment: I want to avoid using a shell script, I want to generate a .jar file afterwards.

Comment: Threads are obvious solution to call independent methods in  parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Threads. You can create multiple threads and start them all at the same time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

EDIT: maybe this helps too. [How to run two methods simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664036/how-to-run-two-methods-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a main *dispatcher*, that creates [Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) that will invoke each client main method.

```
public class Dispatcher {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
      final Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> Client1.main(args1));
      final Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> Client2.main(args2));
      final Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> Client3.main(args3));

      thread1.start();
      thread2.start();
      thread3.start();

      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
      thread3.join();
   }
}
```

You have to figure out how to pass the arguments (`args1`, `args2`, `args3`), this is not detailed in the question.

Thread.[join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) is used to wait for the Threads to finish, if you want to do some later actions (prompt something for example).
If you don't call it, it will still work because they are not [daemon threads](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_005.htm), but you won't be able to do actions **after** they are finished.

However, with more context, we may provide you a better solution and avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).