# Call another method B when method A is called

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way in Java using reflection or any, to call a method or a class when a custom method is called.

I have a packed library.jar, in which **Foo.class** has method **doThat(String a, MyObject b)**

```
public class Foo {
    public Object doThat(String a, MyObject b) {
      // do something
      return null;
    }
}
```

I need a trigger my custom method **Bar#doThis**, when **Foo#doThat** is called.

```
public class Bar {
    public boolean doThis(String a, MyObject b) {
      // did it.
      return true;
    }
}
```

I will not be able to extract the jar and inject listeners. *Foo.class* is as similar as **java.util.ArrayList** or **final class java.util.zip.ZipCoder**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664036/how-to-run-two-methods-simultaneously  or probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162863/how-to-run-different-methods-parallely ?

Comment: Where is the Foo instance being used? Are you providing the Foo instance to another object which is calling that method and you need to indirect that? You might be able to wrap the foo instance with a foo subclass that delegates all calls to the foo instance, except for doThat which can trigger a callback, then call mFoo.doThat();

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my initial question, make a custom subclass that delegates all of foo's calls to the original `foo` object, except for doThat which you override, call your `bar.doThis`, and then call the actual `foo.doThat`. You can do this two ways, first by subclassing the original `Foo` class if you are creating `Foo`s yourself, or you can just make a wrapper class that straight delegates to a `Foo` you don't get to create

```
class SubFoo extends Foo {

    public SubFoo(fooParams..., Bar bar) {
        //...
        this.mFoo = new Foo(fooParams);
        this.mBar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object doThat(String a, MyObject b) {
        this.mBar.doThis(a, b);
        this.mFoo.doThat(a, b);
    }
    //Other methods Foo has that just call into this.foo
}
```

This should work as long as `Foo` isn't marked `final` or you can just delegate straight to foo

```
class DelegateToFoo extends Foo {

    public DelegateToFoo(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        //...
        this.mFoo = foo;
        this.mBar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object doThat(String a, MyObject b) {
        this.mBar.doThis(a, b);
        this.mFoo.doThat(a, b);
    }
    //Other methods Foo has that just call into this.foo
}
```

If `Foo` has an interface you can just implement that and delegate rather than extending the subclass

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is intercepting a method execution. This can be done using [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). You have 2 some alternatives like [aspectj](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) and [Sprint AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

When you can intercept any method in before/after or even override it.

Hope this helps.